# How to batch insert in MSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to make a bulk insert using MYSQL.

Here is my code:

```
  const values = workouts.map((workout) => [
        nanoid(),
        programEnrollmentId,
        workout.workout_id,
        userId, 
      ]);

      await RDS.query(
        `
        INSERT INTO user_workouts (nano_id, program_enrolment_id, workout_id, user_id)
        VALUES ?
        `,
        [values]
      );
```

For some reason I am getting this error:
`ERROR MESSAGE: Named parameter name is empty`

When I add an extra square brackets to the values, like this `[[values]]` I get this error:
`ERROR MESSAGE: Unexpected key '0' found in params.parameterSets[0][0]`

Comment: what library are you using to perform queries? what are the contents of `values`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql

Comment: And if you remove the brackets ? Because values is already an array of array

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the package, that point out to that documentation https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

```js
  const values = workouts.map((workout) => [
        nanoid(),
        programEnrollmentId,
        workout.workout_id,
        userId, 
      ]);

  await RDS.query(
        `
        INSERT INTO user_workouts (nano_id, program_enrolment_id, workout_id, user_id)
        VALUES ?
        `,
        values
      );
```

You don't neeed the bracket as the variable values is already an array of array